# Hiding a portion of the UI in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a group of controls (edittexts, buttons etc..) which I want to show/hide programmatically, without showing/hiding them one by one. I have read about fragments and view groups but couldn't figure out how to use them for this purpose. How to do this, any examples?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method would be to wrap the portions you want to hide in a single Layout container with an ID (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, etc - whichever you need).  Then programmatically set the visibility.

```
LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(r.layout.myLayout);
myLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

or 
myLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

You could also start the layout either visible or not in the XML.

Comment: +1 for Tim's idea if you already have a surrounding parent layer that encompasses everything you need to show/hide.

Comment: I don't see it that way, using the layout as a wrapper seems appropriate when required.  If there's 5 objects, I'd prefer to wrap them and change one setting, rather than change 5.  While it might take a fraction longer to process the layout, memory-wise you're saving the creation of 4 extra objects which would need to be collected.

Answer (score -1):

`View.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` or `View.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`

Will control visibility, you can also use `GONE` but that may change your layout, which could or couldn't be desired.

Comment: He doesn't want to do them one at a time.  He already knows how to do that ;)